# my docker-compose is failing on this line. Why?

Tags: docker-compose

I need to copy a php.ini file that I have (with xdebug enabled) to /bitnami/php-fpm/conf/. I am using a bitnami docker container, and I want to use xdebug to debug the php code in my app. Therefore I must enable xdebug in the php.ini file. The /bitnami/php-fpm container on the repository had this comment added to it:

**5.5.30-0-r01 (2015-11-10)
php.ini is now exposed in the volume mounted at /bitnami/php-fpm/conf/ allowing users to change the defaults as per their requirements.**

So I am trying to copy my php.ini file to /bitnami/php-fpm/conf/php.ini in the docker-compose.yml. Here is the php-fpm section of the .yml:

```
  php-fpm:
    image: bitnami/php-fpm:5.5.26-3
  volumes:
     - ./app:/app
     - php.ini:/bitnami/php-fpm/conf
   networks:
      - net
volumes:
  database_data:
    driver: local
networks:
  net:
```

Here is the error I get: ERROR: Named volume "php.ini:/bitnami/php-fpm/conf:rw" is used in service "php-fpm" but no declaration was found in the volumes section.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Is the indentation shown here really what you have in your `docker-compose.yml`?

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that your indentation is correct otherwise you probably wouldn't get that error. Always run your yaml's through a lint tool such as http://www.yamllint.com/.

In terms of your volume mount, the first one you have the correct syntax but the second you don't therefore Docker thinks it is a named volume.

Assuming `php.ini` is in the root directory next to your `docker-compose.yml`.

```
  volumes:
     - ./app:/app
     - ./php.ini:/bitnami/php-fpm/conf
```

Comment: Thanks. I really have no understanding of syntax in a docker-compile.yml. I tried your change but I get this warning: WARNING: Service "php-fpm" is using volume "/bitnami/php-fpm/conf" from the previous container. Host mapping "/opt/docker-substantiator/php.ini" has no effect. Remove the existing containers (with `docker-compose rm php-fpm`) to use the host volume mapping.

Comment: Run the following commands: `docker-compose down` and then `docker-compose up -d`. The `docker-compose down` command will stop and destroy your containers.

Comment: You also really should try and understand the yaml syntax. It has become so important to know in recent years and through my early days, indents/spacing has really wasted a lot of my time troubleshooting issues. As mentioned, use http://www.yamllint.com/.

Comment: Now I get  strange error after making the change. I will post another question about it.